# Problema para acceder a una aplicacion Laravel desde clientes remotos en un servidor Ubuntu Linux 16.04

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, apache, virtualhost

tengo un sistema ya terminado en Laravel 5.5, logre crear un virtualhost, el archivo de configuracion es este:

```
"/etc/apache2/sites-available/aplicacion_laravel.local.conf"


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName aplicacion_laravel.local

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    #Ruta donde esta el proyecto
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/aplicacion_laravel/public


    <Directory /var/www/html/aplicacion_laravel/public>

        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

    </Directory>



    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Ahora en el archivo "/etc/hosts" agregue la linea

```
127.0.0.1   aplicacion_laravel.local
```

Aplique los comandos para agregar la configuración:

```
# sudo a2ensite aplicacion_laravel.local.conf

# sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Y reinicie el servidor apache, con esto logre acceder a la aplicación local escribiendo la url en el navegador web, seria "http://aplicacion_laravel.local".

Todo bien, el problema es que necesito saber **¿como hago para acceder a mi aplicación desde un dispositivo remoto?**, ya sea una tablet, teléfono inteligente o pc. Puede ser por la Ip del servidor o nombre del equipo. 
Quiero aclarar que en un servidor Windows con Xampp lo logre sin problema, pero en Ubuntu Linux no he tenido éxito. 
Espero que me puedan ayudar, con este inconveniente.

Comment: Dudo mucho que sea una configuración de Virtualhost. ¿Ya probaste editando el .htaccess de Laravel?

Comment: Hola Fernando, Gracias por responder, la verdad no he probado editando el .htaccess de Laravel, y no tengo conocimiento para saber editarlo

Comment: Por favor lee esta referencia en inglés que te ayudará a saber cómo guardar el proyecto de laravel en un servidor y echarlo a andar https://mediastroke.com/blog/host-laravel-project/